# Run a case when statement and continue evaluating even after earlier conditions are met

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I understand that in SQL Server case when statements, that when the first true condition is met, the expression is evaluated and all subsequent when statements are skipped.  My question is simply, is there some way to continue evaluating and MODIFYING the resulting expression even after the first statement is true?

So for example, suppose I have a database record in a column called my_column that has the string value '`ABCDEFG`'.  I want to be able to do something like this:

```
select
    case when my_column like '%A%' then REPLACE(my_column, 'A', 'M') 
         when my_column like '%M%' then REPLACE(my_column, 'M', 'N')
    end as new_column
from my_table
```

I'd then like my resulting value to be '`NBCDEFG`'

So essentially I'm trying to cascade changes from one when statement to the next.

Comment: `case` is an *expresson* not a *statement* which answers your question - its not about running code its about returning a value, a single value. Why do you even need a case in the situation you describe? Why not just call replace unconditionally?

Comment: Pedantics aside, this is just a toy example.  In the real problem, I am trying to replace multiple subsequent update statements with a single case (or something similar) that is algorithmic in nature in how it manipulates the strings.  There's a first step, a second step, third, etc. in order to manipulate the string according to specifications.

Comment: You have to nest them then.

Comment: Make your example representative. Boiling down your example to essentials is good, but if it's not representative of the actual problem it's not useful (and will invite useless answers). There is no simple silver bullet like a `CONTINUE`, and depending on the actual problem the best strategy may well turn out to be a complete rewrite of the statement (SQL is interesting like that).

Comment: `CROSS APPLY(VALUES` probably very useful in this instance. @DaleK 's comment is not just pedantics, it's the reason you even had such a question

Comment: @Charlieface w3schools is at fault here... they insist on calling it a statement.

Comment: @DaleK, aka w3fools...

Comment: @Charlieface yeah either a string of CROSS APPLY VALUES or a string of CTEs, but it won't be pretty either way. You COULD make a TVF with all the ugly logic and utilize that.

Answer (score 0):

Simply nest your replace

```
Select REPLACE(REPLACE(my_column, 'A', 'M'),'M','N') new_column
from
my_table
```

Comment: Possibly a case for a series of applys() if there is additional logic to factor in - that wasn't in the original question though, the goal posts moved all too quickly ;-)

Comment: Yip - although while applies look pretty they are still in essence nesting case expressions.